# Realm/Swift: compilation error: Missing argument for parameter 'forPrimaryKey' in call

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to get my head around swift & realm, so I've created some kind of a test pad programme.

My model is defined like so

```
class RealmRecord: Object {

    // properties
    dynamic var id: Int = 0;
    dynamic var text: String = ""
    dynamic var var1: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var var2: Int = 0
    dynamic var var3: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var var4: Int = 0
    dynamic var cdate: Date = Date()
    dynamic var cusr: String = ""
    dynamic var mdate: Date = Date.distantPast
    dynamic var musr: String = ""
    dynamic var mcnt: Int = 0

    // methods
    convenience init(id: Int? = 0, text: String? = "", var1: Double? = 0.0,
                     var2: Int? = 0, var3: Double? = 0.0, var4: Int? = 0,
                     cusr: String? = "") {

        self.init()

        self.id = id!
        self.text = text!
        self.var1 = var1!
        self.var2 = var2!
        self.var3 = var3!
        self.var4 = var4!
        self.cdate = Date()
        self.cusr = cusr!
        self.mdate = Date.distantPast
        self.musr = ""
        self.mcnt = 0

    } // init

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    } // primaryKey

} // RealmRecord
```

Persisting the data is accomplished by

```
try recRealm?.write {
    recRealm?.add(self.rec, update: true)
} // try
```

But when adding the data retrieval via

```
if let inrec = self.recRealm?.object(RealmRecord.self) {
    return inrec
} else {
    return List<RealmRecord>()
} // if/else
```

I'm receiving an error message while compiling the code, reading

```
DataRealmRecord.swift:84:39: Missing argument for parameter 'forPrimaryKey' in call
```

Looking at the Realm documentation reveals only retrieving all persisted data--apparently without having a primary key defined--, or, alternatively, a single object, specified by the primary key.

Sifting through The Net brings up pretty much the same.

Given the model above, how can I retrieve all persisted data?

-- Sil68

EDIT

I've also defined a class facilitating this Realm model of mine, which basically carries out the following steps:

- generate some random data;
- persist data via the Realm model;
- read data in again;
- compare generated with read data.

The code

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class DataRealmRecord {
    // properties
    private(set) var recDBPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    private(set) var recDBSubPath = "Persistency"
    private(set) var recDBFile = "data.realm"
    private(set) var recRealm: Realm?
    private(set) var recRealmCfg: Realm.Configuration?
    private(set) var rec = List<RealmRecord>()
    private(set) var startTime = 0.0
    private(set) var stopTime = 0.0
    private(set) var runTime = 0.0
    private(set) var outLog = ""
    private(set) var realmOk = false

    // methods
    init() {
        // assemble destination folder/database name
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: recDBPath + "/" +
            recDBSubPath,
            withIntermediateDirectories: true,
            attributes: nil)
            recDBFile = recDBPath + "/" + recDBSubPath + "/" + recDBFile
            realmOk = true
        } catch let error as NSError {
            outLog += error.localizedDescription
            realmOk = false
        } // do/try/catch
        // configure realm database
        if (realmOk) {
            self.recRealmCfg = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: Foundation.URL(string: self.recDBFile))

            do {
                self.recRealm = try Realm(configuration: self.recRealmCfg!)
                realmOk = true
            } catch let error as NSError {
                outLog += error.localizedDescription
                realmOk = false
            } // do/try/catch
        } // if
    } // init

    // generate test data
    func generateData(noRecs: Int? = 1000, simDat: SimulateData?) {
        for i in 1...noRecs! {
            let realmRec = RealmRecord(id: i,
                                       text: String(format: "Record #%04d", i),
                                       var1: simDat?.datnorm[i - 1] ?? 1.1,
                                       var2: simDat?.datpois[i - 1] ?? 2,
                                       var3: simDat?.datunif[i - 1] ?? 3.3,
                                       var4: simDat?.datbern[i - 1] ?? 4,
                                       cusr: "me")
                                       self.rec.append(realmRec)
        } // for
    } // generateData

    // retrieve test data from persistent storage
    func loadData() -> List<RealmRecord> {
        if let inrec = self.recRealm?.object(RealmRecord.self) {
            return inrec
        } else {
            return List<RealmRecord>()
        } // if/else
    } // loadData

    // save test data to persistent storage
    func saveData() {
        do {
            try recRealm?.write {
                recRealm?.add(self.rec, update: true)
            } // try
        } catch let error as NSError {
            outLog += error.localizedDescription
        } // do/try/catch
    } // saveData

    // compare two data sets
    func compareData(rec1: List<RealmRecord>, rec2: List<RealmRecord>) -> Bool {
        var rc = false
        if rec1.count == rec2.count {
            rc = true
            for i in 0..<rec1.count {
                rc = rc && (rec1[i] == rec2[i])
            } // for
        } // if
        return rc
    } // compareData

    // run a full evaluation cycle
    // (1) generate test data;
    // (2) save test data to persistant storage;
    // (3) retrieve test data from persistant storage;
    // (4) compare generated data with retrieved data.
    func fullCycle(noRecs: Int? = 1000, simDat: SimulateData?, prnData: Bool? = false) {
        // start execution time measurement
        self.startTime = Double(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent())
        // execute the full cycle
        self.generateData(noRecs: noRecs, simDat: simDat)           // (1)
        self.saveData()                                             // (2)
        let rec2 = self.loadData()                                  // (3)
        let cmpRec = compareData(rec1: self.rec, rec2: rec2)        // (4)
        // stop execution time measurement & calculate elapsed time
        self.stopTime = Double(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent())
        self.runTime = self.stopTime - self.startTime
    } // fullCycle
} // DataRealmRecord
```

Issue at hand is, this code fails to compile due to the error message mentioned above (in method ***loadData()***).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift compiler is telling you that it thinks you're trying to call [`Realm.object(ofType:forPrimaryKey:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6objectu0_RxCS_6ObjectrFT6ofTypeMx13forPrimaryKeyq__GSqx_), which retrieves a single object based on the value of its primary key. It sounds like you really want to call [`Realm.objects(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm7objectsuRxCS_6ObjectrFMxGCS_7Resultsx_) to retrieve all objects of a given type. Note that this returns a `Results<T>`, not a `List<T>`.

Comment: Indeed, that's the case, I want to retrieve all the data, regardless of any key. Is there an option of accomplishing this, albeit the model is defining a primary key? And how can I get List<T> instead of Result<T>?

Comment: `Realm.objects(_:)` gives you all objects of the given type, regardless of whether they define a primary key or have any particular value for their primary key. And `Results<T>` is what will be returned. Why do you want `List<T>`? `List<T>`s can only be created as a property of a model class.

Comment: Because you're trying to call a method `Realm.object(_:)`, which doesn't exist. You want `Realm.objects(_:)`.

Comment: Ooops! Bad & silly me! Thanks for pointing the finger at the right spot!

Comment: Thanks again! Now--after appending this little "s" to "object"--all is in best order! :) And returning "List(inrec)" solved the other issue!